# ">>>" operator - what is used for?

Tags: javascript, operators

I was just looking through Mozilla Developer documentation, and found notation that I don't know what is used for and also cannot find any information through internet.

[Array filter polyfill - line 10](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var t = Object(this);
var len = t.length >>> 0;
```

Any suggestions what this operator is for ?

Comment: It is a [bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**

```
t.length >>> 0;
```

actually tries to get a valid 32 bit unsigned integer from `t.length`. For what we know, `t.length` could be of any type (an object, array, string etc). `>>> 0` returns the value unaltered if it is already a  valid 32 bit unsigned number. For example,

```
console.log({} >>> 0);
// 0
console.log([] >>> 0);
// 0
console.log("Google" >>> 0);
// 0
```

Normally, this bitwise trick is used to avoid a `if` block type checking, like this

```
var len = 0;
if (typeof data === 'number') {
    len = data;
}
```

We might still have to convert `len` to an integer, if it is a floating point value.

**Explanation**

`>>>` is called Zero-fill right shift operator. Apart from being used as a bitwise operator, it is used to get a 32 bit numeric value out of an object. The [ECMA Script 5.1 Specification for `>>>`](http://es5.github.io/#x11.7.3) says that

> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *ShiftExpression*.
> 2. Let *lval* be GetValue(*lref*).
> 3. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *AdditiveExpression*.
> 4. Let *rval* be GetValue(*rref*).
> 5. Let *lnum* be ToUint32(*lval*).
> 6. Let *rnum* be ToUint32(*rval*).
> 7. Let *shiftCount* be the result of masking out all but the least significant 5 bits of *rnum*, that is, compute *rnum* & 0x1F.
> 8. Return the result of performing a zero-filling right shift of *lnum* by *shiftCount* bits. Vacated bits are filled with zero. **The result is an unsigned 32-bit integer.**

It basically converts both the operands to 32 bit unsigned integer (Step 5 and 6) and shifts the left hand side expression, right hand side expression times.

If we look at the [definition of `ToInt32`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.6),

> 1. Let *number* be the result of calling ToNumber on the input argument.
> 2. If *number* is NaN, +0, −0, +∞, or −∞, return +0.
> 3. Let *posInt* be sign(*number*) * floor(abs(*number*)).
> 4. Let *int32bit* be *posInt* modulo 2<sup>32</sup>; that is, a finite integer value *k* of Number type with positive sign and less than 2<sup>32</sup> in magnitude such that the mathematical difference of *posInt* and *k* is mathematically an integer multiple of 2<sup>32</sup>.
> 5. Return *int32bit*.

First the argument is converted to a number (if it is a not a valid number then `NaN` will be returned by `ToNumber`). And step 4 makes sure that you return a valid number in the range 0 to 2<sup>32</sup>.

Comment: _*bows to the superior answer*_  +1 (It seems dogs reign supreme on this question ;-) )

Comment: Now it is perfectly clear! Thanks! BTW, this seems to be very good question for JS ninja job interview :)

Comment: @kuba: I don't think someone can expect a developer to know this. However, with the documentation accessible...

Answer (score 4):

It's a ["Zero-fill right shift"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Unsigned_right_shift) (bitwise) operator.

> This operator shifts the first operand the specified number of bits to the right. Excess bits shifted off to the right are discarded. Zero bits are shifted in from the left. The sign bit becomes `0`, so the result is always non-negative.
>
> For non-negative numbers, zero-fill right shift and sign-propagating right shift yield the same result. For example, `9 >>> 2` yields `2`, the same as `9 >> 2`:
>
> However, this is not the case for negative numbers. For example, `-9 >>> 2` yields `1073741821`, which is different than `-9 >> 2` (which yields `-3`):

[@thefourtheye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1903116/thefourtheye) [answered with a good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31342113/1835379) about the usage of this operator.